# Install the diagnostics extension inside a service fabric VM manually

Tags: azure

I have a 5-node service fabric cluster which is running atop of a scale set. For some reason one of the VMs reports that the extension **Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics.IaaSDiagnostics** is stuck in the ProvisioningState/transitioning state.

Here's the complete error message:

> Error while processing plugin Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics.IaaSDiagnostics version 1.11.3.0, state: enabled, error: Plugin manifest deserialization has failed with exception: No plugin manifest file C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Azure.Diagnostics.IaaSDiagnostics\1.10.1.1\HandlerManifest.json found under the plugin folder

Apparently, it's trying to access the manifest file which does not exist anymore.

I was wondering whether it's possible to reinstall/reinitialize this extension manually? I haven't found a way to perform this through the Azure PowerShell. The cmdlet **Set-AzureRmVMDiagnosticsExtension** requires explicit defining of the ResourceGroupName property, and I don't quite understand what must be specified here since the VMs are actually in the scale set.

Any suggestions are appreciated.